WildFly 32.0.0 and Java 17 Access API RESTful
I have a problem wanting to connect to my EndPoints from Postam, my application is deployed correctly in WildFly 32.0.0. but when I want to access my EndPoints it doesn't let me know if anyone knows if I should configure something so that I have access.
enter image description here
Intente ingresar desde POSTMAN  pero me da este error.
enter image description here

It looks like your application is secured and you're not sending the credentials required.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
